# mysql load file field preceeded by character

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL that loads a file into a temporary table on a regular basis.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE itemsfile
INTO TABLE tmp_items 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

The file is now being changed to a csv. However, some of the fields will now be enclosed with double quotes, and will also be preceded by an equals sign. so instead of:

```
1234|6663663
```

it'll look like:

```
="1234",="6663663"
```

I will change the third line in the query to be:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

But how do I handle the '='? I really just want it to be ignored.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that you run d shell or perlscript before loading?

Comment: No, its run by a php script, nothing else involved.